# in audio signal, what are the advantages and disadvantages of increasing and decreasing sample rate?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, sample-rate

Also, what are pros and cons of changing quantization steps?
These questions been wondering over my head and i wasn't able to find any suitable answer anywhere else. would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it an homework?
In any case:
increasing sample rate: audio reproduction is more accurate but memory occupation is higher
decreasing sample rate: memory occupation is lower but audio reproduction is less accurate
Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)) for more detailed information

Comment: I'd argue that bit depth (resolution) has more to do with  audio being more accurate, not sampling rate. A lower sample rate simply means that the maximum (Nyquist) frequency will be lower (half the sampling rate)